# Magento client side cache issue on first load itself

Tags: php, magento, caching

I am using magento 1.9.2.2.
I have disabled all cache from admin. Here's my site link. http://cmcollective.net/beta/

Issue here is on page first load itself cache is getting generated on client side. Thus if i change currency or update cart quantity, etc. then changes are not taking effect on browser. If i do force refresh with ctrl+shift+R then changes are visible.

How come so much cache get generated on client side. It seems like complete site is getting cached. Please visit site to experience this issue. 
Tried all mentioned stuffs all over the site. Tried disabling most of the modules, deleted files in cache folders manually.
Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured **Cache-Control:max-age=10800** and **Expires** headers. It makes browser cache your html page for 3 hours. To prevent browser from caching a page completely, you can set following headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
Expires:Fri, 18 Mar 1999 12:22:21 GMT
```

Note that **Pragma** header is for **HTTP 1.0**, and **Cache-Control:max-age** is equivalent to **Expires**, but **Cache-Control:max-age** has higher priority, so there is no reason to have them both simultaneously

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you tell me which file should i change. I don't know how is it coming as i didn't added it. I checked htaccess file but nothing for cache is there

Comment: I you use Apache http server, then this document is for you https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html

Comment: Not sure what to do but i tried changing adding Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache" to htaccess but nothing changed. Another thing i would like to bring in you notice is same site is hosted on another domain and is working with Cache-Control:max-age=10800. Check here http://happytreeservices.com/cmcollective/

Comment: I see different headers on second domain: https://s.mail.ru/JDLH3ruZnfoU/img-2016-03-18-12-39-59.png

Comment: Ok i was looking at sourceview :(   Should i disable mod_headers from server?

Comment: You should configure it properly to return right headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106700/discussion-between-alok-and-vitaly-kulikov).

Comment: app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/html/head.phtml This theme file has cache control set to max-age=10800 which was overwriting all my cache control setting. Just changed it as suggested by @Vitaly and its Solved.